# Static instance array in instance method

Tags: php, oop, cakephp

The [I18n class in CakePHP](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/I18n/I18n.php) provides this method to create instances:

```
public static function getInstance() {
    static $instance = array();
    if (!$instance) {
        $instance[0] = new I18n();
    }
    return $instance[0];
}
```

Among other considerations (please correct me if I'm wrong), I understand it helps to use class instances from the [convenience functions](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/basics.php):

```
/**
 * Returns a translated string if one is found; Otherwise, the submitted message.
 */
function __($singular, $args = null) {
    // ...
    $translated = I18n::translate($singular);
    // ...
}
```

```
echo __('Hello, World!');
```

This looks cleaner than having to pass the instance around as argument (or, even worse, using a randomly named global variable). But I can't imagine a reason why `$instance` is an array rather than a plain object.

What can be the purpose of using a one-item array to store class instances?

Comment: The only purpose I can imagine is restricting number of instances to 1 (that assume rewriting previous instance). But in this case there is no need to use `array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect this to be leftovers from older PHP4/CakePHP versions where the instances were assigned by reference.

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.2.0/cake/libs/i18n.php**

```
function &getInstance() {
    static $instance = array();
    if (!$instance) {
        $instance[0] =& new I18n();
        $instance[0]->l10n =& new L10n();
    }
    return $instance[0];
}
```

```
$_this =& I18n::getInstance();
```

Assigning by reference doesn't work with `static`, [**the reference is not being *remembered***](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.references), but [**it works when assigned to an array entry**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#37427).

So this was most probably just a workaround for a PHP limitation.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for this is to keep all `singleton` class instances in one global - (`static` *is a synonym of global in this case*) array variable for monitoring or not messing the global/local namespace with individual variables for each singleton. If each of the `static` variables were with random names e.g `$translated` it would be more easier to overwrite and mess its value. - bug again for me, this is extremely rear possibility.

For example the `I18Nn` instance would be with `[0]` key, other class would have other key. You should check outher `singleton` classes how manage the `static $instance` array values.

Comment: Singleton doesn't explain why `$instance` is an array rather than a plain object—you accomplish the same with a plain object. (You'd also need to make your constructor private/protected.)

Comment: Yes, you can accomplish this by a `plain` object, buy you need to figure out a unique name for it, as it is meant to be cached(`static`). The array used in this case will contain all such objects.

Comment: A unique name? What's wrong with `$instance`? Why do you say "all such objects", in plural, if there's only `$instance[0]`? I think it's just legacy code, as @ndm explains.